# ClassCastException (Gallery + ImageView)

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have followed a tutorial to create a gallery with an imageview below it. All I want to do is place the gallery on the bottom and the imageview above it, but when I switch them around in the XML it gives me a ClassCastException.

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That is the non-working version, but placing gallery above imageview works.

From log:

```
01-26 22:20:13.673: E/AndroidRuntime(349): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:         android.widget.ImageView
01-26 22:20:13.673: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at     com.appinfluence.fanapp.v1.Photos.onCreate(Photos.java:36)
```

onCreate:

```
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Photos.this));

    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);


    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]); 
        }
    });
}
```

Other helpful code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
```

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_I2Ctfz7eew4/S_JxIfgKrfI/AAAAAAAAAzA/m1KUSIugojY/s1600/Gallery2.1.PNG]

Comment: Yeah, i am also getting same problem if ImageView is above and Gallery is below.

Comment: Can you show us this piece of code too: com.appinfluence.fanapp.v1.Photos.onCreate(Photos.java:36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey NickNelson Just now i got the solution to your problem, just clean the project it will work.

**Sample screenshot**

[image]

Comment: why is there a gap at the top?

Comment: gap between **4/7** and Google image ?? because of image height.

Comment: check now replaced screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use separate `ImageView` in the layout, **Gallery** will display the images. Remove the `ImageView` and check it..

**edit**

just clean the project . ( as yugandhar said.)

Comment: that doesn't make sense because I am using imageview to display the images in the gallery when clicked. I used this tutorial: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html

Comment: are you getting gallery iamges.

Comment: Yes I am pulling images from an array of drawables it looks like the picture i am about to edit in my question but I want to reverse the order of them.

Comment: I think you are getting the 2 mixed up.. I want it to be the opposite of what the screenshot above has. So the big picture on top and the sliding bar at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this XML for the layout section:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/antartica1"/>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```